# How to insert multiple table rows after specific row with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table where each row has a data element. Something like this:

```
<tr class="logreader-header-row">
   <td class="logtable-header" colspan="100%" data-date="2015-05-12">
      <img class="logreader-header-controller" src="images/logreader-dropdown.png">
      2015-05-12
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="logreader-header-row">
   <td class="logtable-header" colspan="100%" data-date="2015-05-11">
      <img class="logreader-header-controller" src="images/logreader-dropdown.png">
      2015-05-11
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="logreader-header-row">
   <td class="logtable-header" colspan="100%" data-date="2015-05-07">
      <img class="logreader-header-controller" src="images/logreader-dropdown.png">
      2015-05-07
   </td>
</tr>
```

Every row has an onclick event attached to. When the user clicks the row the data attribute is being send to the server with an AJAX request:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $(".logtable-header").each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            var header_row = $(this).parent("logreader-header-row");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: URL+'admin/ajax_processor/getLog',
                data:{date:$(this).data("date")},
                success: function(response){
                    header_row.after(response);
                },
                error: function(request, status, error){
                    console.log(request);
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The AJAX response contains the HTML code of a subset of table rows generated on the server. What I want is to insert these rows after the one that has been clicked. Here is what I have in the AJAX response:

```
<tr class="logtable-oddrow-notice">
    <td>2015-04-27</td>
    <td>08:55:07</td>
    <td>NOTICE</td>
    <td>ERROR 404 Requested url: "http://localhost/PH-SERVER_MIRROR/frontend/index/" not found! (user:unidentified[id:-])</td>
</tr>

<tr class="logtable-evenrow-notice">
    <td>2015-04-27</td>
    <td>09:21:08</td>
    <td>NOTICE</td>
    <td>'Test'[id:30] user succesfully logged in.</td>
</tr>

<tr class="logtable-oddrow-notice">
    <td>2015-04-27</td>
    <td>10:13:37</td>
    <td>NOTICE</td>
    <td>New newsletter created: "Teszt 2" by user:Test[id:30]</td>
</tr>
```

`header_row` is the parent `<tr>` element of the clicked `<td>` element:

```
var header_row = $(this).parent("logreader-header-row");
```

But I can't insert the response after the clicked `<tr>`:

```
success: function(response){
    header_row.after(response);
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Class dot missed at `var header_row = $(this).parent("logreader-header-row");`

Comment: why you need  .on('click')  inside .each();  I think its useless

Comment: `$(".logtable-header").on("click", function(){...` will register the event for all td elements with mentioned class, so is not necessary to loop here.

Comment: You can simplify by attaching the click handler to the `tr.logreader-header-row` elements rather than their one and only `td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logreader-header-row` is a class, meaning to select it you need to prefix it with a `.` character (the [Class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)).

```
var header_row = $(this).parent(".logreader-header-row");
```

Otherwise your code here is searching for a `<logreader-header-row>` element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the class selector on the `parent()` call: `parent('.logreader-header-row')` (Note the `.`)

That said, it's better practice to use `closest()` in this case as it will stop at the first match. Also, you don't need to use the `each()` function to assign the events. Try this:

```
$(".logtable-header").click(function(){
    var header_row = $(this).closest(".logreader-header-row");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: URL + 'admin/ajax_processor/getLog',
        data: { date: $(this).data("date") },
        success: function(response) {
            header_row.after(response);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
            console.log(request);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add event listener in the loop. You can use event delegation. Use `on` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").on('click', "tr.logtable-header", function () {
        var header_row = $(this).parent("logreader-header-row");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL + 'admin/ajax_processor/getLog',
            data: {
                date: $(this).data("date")
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(this).closest('.logreader-header-row').after(response);
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(request);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```